# Unity iOS project 'FBSDKShareKit/FBSDKShareKit.h' file not found

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, unity-game-engine

I use Unity 2019.3.0f3 for export Unity to iOS as Framework.
And when I open exported iOS project I get the issue [image]

but I can navigate to this header use "Cmd+click".
I googled and tried almost all solutions which I could find
I tried set home directory for `Framework Search Path` to `'$(HOME)/Documents/FacebookSDK'`
also tried set `FBSDKShareKit.Framework` as embeddedFramework and Pods install. Nothing helped

How can I figure out it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it just downgrade FacebookSDK to 7.16.1 and update Firebase SDK for Unity.

Answer (score 2):

I solved it temporarily by downgrading to Facebook SDK version 7.15.1 & removed #include "RegisterMonoModules.h" from FBunityInterface.h

Comment: How did you downgrade Facebook SDK in Unity? Just download the Facebook SDK 7.16.1 and install?

Comment: You can find it here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/downloads/

Comment: This is the main support forum for Facebook SDK, perhaps it's better post there in the future:
https://github.com/facebook/facebook-sdk-for-unity

Comment: Thx, but I think that a rough issue, look like I have to downgrade Unity and lose opportunity to create Unity.Framework

Answer (score 2):

I solved it by changing it as follows. No need to downgrade Facebook SDK.

My Envrionment:

- Unity v2020.1.6f
- Facebook SDK v9.1.0
- XCode v12.5

Solution:

Goto Unity --> Play Service Resolver -->
iOS Resolver --> Settings -->  Cocoapods Integration: Select `XCode Project - Add Cocoapods to XCode project`

Reason:

Because its default setting is to `add Cocoapods to the XCode workspace.` This is the cause of this issue due to the missing FBSDKShareKit framework.

If you set up `Add Cocoapods to XCode project` properly, you will see Pods.proj with FBSDKShareKit framework imported into XCode Project.

Remember you need to install cocoapods properly on your Mac.
Otherwise, Pods.proj won't be imported into your XCode Project.

If not, run

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

Then check it, run

```
pod
```

You should be able to see the command's description.

Hope this will be helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working when building on Mac using 2019.2.17 + pod install and exporting from the xcode workspace file, not the xcodeproj file.

Comment: Does it version of Unity support export as framework?

Comment: I have no idea :)